# Can SSH and SFTP *off* server but can't SFTP *to* server?

Tags: sftp

As in the description, I can make an SSH connection to the host and I can copy files *off* the host to my own computer with SFTP, but I can't copy files *to* the host with SFTP.

Other users on this host can copy files both to and from the host with SFTP, and I've tried using different computers and different SSH/SFTP client software to connect to the server; none of them work.  I've checked my disk quota to make sure I have adequate space for new files.  So as far as I can tell, this problem seems to be strictly user-specific.

What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Without any error message or debug log it is impossible to help.

Comment: Try putting a very small file into `/tmp` on the remote host, both with `scp small_local_file user@remote_host:/tmp` and with `sftp`. If write permissions are the problem, at least this should work.

Comment: Please add information to the question, such as the output of `ssh -vvv <server>`, or similar.  This will provide valuable insight into possible reasons for this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be a problem of the specific user with lack of *write permission* to the server specific location.

If you can login into the server, you should make sure that the directory which you are trying to write to is:

- Owned by the user used in `sftp`
- Owner has write permission to this folder

executing `ls -lsa` on the folder in the server should provide the needed information.